How can I change a date filter based on parameter from single date selection to range in looker
I am exploring ways to enable a filter on a date parameter to function as a date range rather than being limited to a single date value. If anyone has any insights or creative approaches to achieve this, I would appreciate your suggestions.
This is what I am doing currently:
parameter: date_filter {
type: date

# default_value: "now"  # This sets the default value to today's date

}
dimension: filter_bool {
type: yesno

sql:
CASE

  WHEN ${test_date} IS NOT NULL AND DATE({% parameter date_filter %}) = ${test_date} THEN TRUE

  ELSE FALSE
END ;;

}
measure: count_distinct {
type: count_distinct

sql: ${id} ;;

drill_fields: [detail*]

filters: {

  field: filter_bool

  value: "yes"

}

}
When using the date_filter parameter as a quick filter in a Looker dashboard or look, it currently only allows selecting a single date at a time. However, I would like it to support selecting a range of dates, or options like “yesterday,” which is typically available with a standard date filter.
Could you please advise if there’s a way to achieve this functionality?
